# What is the X3 header on the Arduino Duemilanove used for?

Tags: arduino

Just got my new Ardunio, was up and running with my first C program in just 5 minutes :)
[image: Schematic of Arduino Duemilanove]
Looking at the schematic, it looks like the X3 header goes to the hardware handshake lines from the USB interface chip.  Any ideas as to what these are typically used for in Ardunio projects?

Comment: I can't see X3 in the schematic.

Comment: Just to the right of pin 9 on IC2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `X3` header [breaks out the unused pins from the FTDI chip](http://hackaday.com/2010/10/09/using-an-arduino-or-seeeduino-for-its-ftdi-chip/). This lets you use the chip for bit banging hacks.

Comment: Cool, how do you control those lines from Windows?

Comment: http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/